# Java issue with String returning Null value, despite using Scanner class to input data

Tags: java, string, null

I am writing a program for a class that is very simple. All it requires of me is to print a grade sheet, and be able to input 3 pieces of information (here represented by Strings `studentName, idNumber`, and `assignmentTitle`). The grade sheet has to be stored in a single string. Ok so this to me appears as though it should work but for whatever reason it outputs null values where the inputted `studentName, idNumber`, and `assignmentTitle` should appear. Very simple problem I'm sure, any ideas? Here is my code.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class GradingForm
{
static String studentName;
static String idNumber;
static String assignmentTitle;
    static String gradeSheet = "********************************* \n\n" + 
                                assignmentTitle + "\n\n" +
                                studentName + " " + idNumber + "\n\n" +
                                "Grade Summary:\n\n" +
                                "Program Correctness:        Quality of Style:\n" +
                                "Late Deduction:              Overall Score:\n" +
                                "Comments:";
public static void gradeFormValues()
{
    Scanner inData;
    inData = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter student's name: ");
    studentName = inData.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Enter student ID number: ");
    idNumber = inData.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Enter Assignment title: ");
    assignmentTitle = inData.nextLine();
}
public static void printGradeSheet()
{
    System.out.println(gradeSheet);
}

public static void main(String[] args)
{
            gradeFormValues();
            printGradeSheet();
}
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is that you use those variables before assigning values to them:

```
static String gradeSheet = "********************************* \n\n" + 
                                assignmentTitle + "\n\n" +
                                studentName + " " + idNumber + "\n\n" +
                                "Grade Summary:\n\n" +
                                "Program Correctness:        Quality of Style:\n" +
                                "Late Deduction:              Overall Score:\n" +
                                "Comments:";
```

You need to build the string only after you assign values to them for example:

```
public static void printGradeSheet()
{
    gradeSheet = "********************************* \n\n" + 
       assignmentTitle + "\n\n" +
       studentName + " " + idNumber + "\n\n" +
       "Grade Summary:\n\n" +
       "Program Correctness:        Quality of Style:\n" +
       "Late Deduction:              Overall Score:\n" +
       "Comments:";
    System.out.println(gradeSheet);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is how your class is instantiated. This is what happens:

```
studentName is set to null

idNumber is set to null

assignmentTitle is set to null

gradeSheet is set using the current values of studentName etc (null).
```

After that you read your data and set the variables, but this does not change the value of gradeSheet already set.

Answer (score 0):

You're problem is the order in which you initialize your variables.

When you initialize `gradeSheet` (the line with `static String gradeSheet =...`), `assignmentTitle`, `studentName`, and `idNumber` are `null`.

You should instead initialize `gradeSheet` after you have finished accepting input from the user.